# Having trouble deselecting all jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-ui-tabs

I set up some jQuery tabs to start off with no tabs selected like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs( { selected: -1 } );
```

Then I also have a separate link that when pressed needs to deselect all the tabs.

```
$("#deselectButton").click(function(){      
    $('#tabs').tabs( 'select' , -1 )
});
```

or

```
$("#deselectButton").click(function(){      
    $('#tabs').tabs( 'selected' , -1 )
});
```

The deselectButton click does deselect the tabs content, however the tabs title remains active with the class 'ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active'.

What is the correct way to deselect all the tabs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("#deselectButton").click(function(){          
    $('#tabs').tabs( 'selected' , -1 )
    $(".ui-tabs-selected").removeClass("ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-tabs-selected");
});
```

Comment: Yes that did it, thank you

    $(".ui-tabs-selected").removeClass("ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-tabs-selected").addClass("ui-state-default");

Comment: Works nicely, but not sure why the plugin skips the second bit by default (?). Last bit can be condensed to:

`$('#tabs').find('.ui-tabs-selected').removeClass( 'ui-state-active ui-tabs-selected' );`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery 1.10 requires the collapsible [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#options) to be set to true.

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'collapsible', true);
$('#tabs').tabs( 'option', 'active', false );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the jQuery UI version 1.9+ then the CSS code has changed to:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', false);
```

or:

```
$('.ui-tabs-active').removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
```

as per comments below. Thanks

Comment: Simpler: $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', false);

Comment: As of 1.10 the first solution doesn't work. The second one still does though.