# Cancel tab selection in jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs, save

I have created some tool that has 4 pages.
I order to navigate between the pages I am using jQuery "tabs" (in the header of each page).

Is there a way to cancel the clicking operation after some tabs was clicked?
For example: If the page wasn't saved the user will get a propper warning: "click YES in order to continue without saving or click NO in order to stay in the unsaved page".

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Comment: I am not clear, what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the jQuery UI tabs widget, you can supply a `select` event when you initialize the tabs, or bind an event handler using the `tabselect` event type:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

or:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

For more information about the jQuery UI Tab widget, see the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select).

In the event handler you should be able to perform whatever checks you require, and stop the tab from changing using `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Hi,
Using the event select or click using event.preventDefault(); prevent loading the other page (stay on the current page as requested) but it highlight the selected tab (after clicking on page 2 I stay in page 4 as requested but tab 2 is highlighted instead tab 4).

Comment: To fix that you could trigger the `select` event in the handler, passing it the index of the current tab. That would make it re-select the current tab: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select

Comment: I added the `$( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 3 );` before the `event.preventDefault();` in the `click` event (In `select` event it doesn't work). The current tab (3) in highlight but in addition to the selected tab (two tabs are highlighted)...

Comment: I add the `$( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", '-1' );` in order to deselect all the tabs but without any change.get error message:        `Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 16
Char: 24805
Code: 0` (checking this error)

Comment: To deselect all the tabs, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438999/having-trouble-deselecting-all-jquery-tabs

Comment: i added the request code `$('.tabs').tabs('selected' , -1 );` and `$(".ui-tabs-selected").removeClass("ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-tabs-selected");` but there are still two highlited tabs...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put a confirm dialog first in the click action. and only continue with the rest of the code if the result from the dialog was true.

Answer (score 0):

In order to cancel or abort the tab's ajax request do something like this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function() {
            // If error occurs while trying to load a page via AJAX, abort the tabs
            $('#tabs').tabs('abort');
        }
    }
});
```

For more information go [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-abort).